# Errors with inter-group communications

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, openmpi

I have to implement a scenario where I have 2 groups. Group 1 contains only process 0 and 1. Group 2 contains all the processes. Now the processes in Group 2 read some data and send it to Group 1(process 0 or 1, equal division). It should look like this:

```
       Grp1  Grp2
Rank
(grp)
 0      0     0
 1      1     1
 2            2
 3            3
 4            4 and so on..
```

Now to implement this, I have used the following code (All the variables and other things are taken care)

```
 program mpi
 use mpi

 integer ierr,new_rank1,new_grp1,new_rank2,new_grp2,new_comm1,new_comm2 
 integer numtasks,rank,orig_grp,tag,sendbuf,recvbuf
 integer ranks1(2),ranks2(8),stat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
 data ranks1 /0,1/,ranks2 /0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7/


 call mpi_init(ierr)
 call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,rank,ierr)
 call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world,numtasks,ierr)

 call MPI_COMM_GROUP(MPI_COMM_WORLD,orig_grp,ierr)
 tag = 342


 call MPI_GROUP_INCL(orig_grp,8,ranks2,new_grp2,ierr)

 call mpi_comm_create_group(mpi_comm_world,new_grp2,112,new_comm2,ierr)

 call mpi_comm_rank(new_comm2,new_rank2,ierr)

 if(new_rank2 == 4) then
    call mpi_send(123,1,MPI_INT,0,tag,new_comm2,ierr) !send a msg from rank 4 of group 2 to rank 0 of group 1
 end if

 if(rank <2) then
   call MPI_GROUP_INCL(orig_grp,2,ranks1,new_grp1,ierr)

 call mpi_comm_create_group(mpi_comm_world,new_grp1,111,new_comm1,ierr)
   call mpi_comm_rank(new_comm1,new_rank1,ierr)

   if(new_rank1 == 0) then
       call mpi_recv(recvbuf,1,MPI_INT,4,tag,new_comm2,stat,ierr)
       print*,recvbuf
     end if
   end if
   call mpi_finalize(ierr)
   end
```

Facing errors in sending and receiving data. The other things work fine. And also if the whole concept is wrong, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: *"Facing errors in sending and receiving data."* You must describe these errors. Also please do not add tags to the title as your `OpenMPI:`. I assume you want a general MPI solution anyway.

Comment: I suggest you replace `.eq.` with `==` to improve readability.

Comment: I suggest that you take a little bit of time to read a book  / documentation about MPI. It will help you to be more productive. A day or two, reading and trying examples in a book will jumpstart your understanding of MPI concepts and before you know it, you will be the one answering question about MPI on SO.

Comment: I can do that. But the thing is I don't deal with MPI at all. Just had to fill in and this is pretty important.

Comment: Fixed recv syntax.